# what is the correct struct to read AWS Config notification?

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, aws-sdk

I am pretty new to go and I have to use aws go sdk to read AWS Config notifications from SQS. (AWS config service -> sns -> sqs)
I was able to get the message. But I want to get into the message get information like resourceType, resourceId, awsRegion.
This is the sample message string(stringified json) I have.
https://gist.github.com/HarishAtGitHub/fcbb01515d11044d04bde14a3d9f6e7a

I am from python background and in python it is easy to do, as the json is like a dictionary. We can easily get it by nested index.
But in go it seems like I should use the right struct to understand this message.

can someone either point me to the right struct or any ideas on how to get the different properties in the message ?

Answer (score 2):

I always use [this](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/) tool to generate struct definitions from JSON blobs. The only thing you have to do yourself is pick a type for the `null` values: it obviously can't determine those, and therefore sets them to `interface{}` (any type implements this).

The struct tags (e.g. `json:"changeType"`) can be omitted if you only want to unmarshal, and not the other way around.

```
type ConfigNotification struct {
    ConfigurationItemDiff struct {
        ChangedProperties struct {
        } `json:"changedProperties"`
        ChangeType string `json:"changeType"`
    } `json:"configurationItemDiff"`
    ConfigurationItem struct {
        RelatedEvents []interface{} `json:"relatedEvents"`
        Relationships []interface{} `json:"relationships"`
        Configuration struct {
            Attachments      []interface{} `json:"attachments"`
            AvailabilityZone string        `json:"availabilityZone"`
            CreateTime       time.Time     `json:"createTime"`
            Encrypted        bool          `json:"encrypted"`
            KmsKeyID         interface{}   `json:"kmsKeyId"`
            Size             int           `json:"size"`
            SnapshotID       string        `json:"snapshotId"`
            State            string        `json:"state"`
            VolumeID         string        `json:"volumeId"`
            Iops             int           `json:"iops"`
            Tags             []struct {
                Key   string `json:"key"`
                Value string `json:"value"`
            } `json:"tags"`
            VolumeType string `json:"volumeType"`
        } `json:"configuration"`
        SupplementaryConfiguration struct {
        } `json:"supplementaryConfiguration"`
        Tags struct {
            Creator string `json:"creator"`
        } `json:"tags"`
        ConfigurationItemVersion     string      `json:"configurationItemVersion"`
        ConfigurationItemCaptureTime time.Time   `json:"configurationItemCaptureTime"`
        ConfigurationStateID         int64       `json:"configurationStateId"`
        AwsAccountID                 string      `json:"awsAccountId"`
        ConfigurationItemStatus      string      `json:"configurationItemStatus"`
        ResourceType                 string      `json:"resourceType"`
        ResourceID                   string      `json:"resourceId"`
        ResourceName                 interface{} `json:"resourceName"`
        ARN                          string      `json:"ARN"`
        AwsRegion                    string      `json:"awsRegion"`
        AvailabilityZone             string      `json:"availabilityZone"`
        ConfigurationStateMd5Hash    string      `json:"configurationStateMd5Hash"`
        ResourceCreationTime         time.Time   `json:"resourceCreationTime"`
    } `json:"configurationItem"`
    NotificationCreationTime time.Time `json:"notificationCreationTime"`
    MessageType              string    `json:"messageType"`
    RecordVersion            string    `json:"recordVersion"`
}
```

Comment: hi, is it in the aws go sdk i can use ?

Comment: this is nice tool, but if my json has different fields tmrw it will break right ? . thats why i was asking for if there is one struct in aws sdk itself